# Selenium css selector for button text and class

Tags: html

HTML CODE LOOK LIKE:

```
<div class="style__ButtonList-kdrevq TBmPt"> <button class="sc-fjdhpX gKYhyw" style="margin-right: 5px; background-color: rgb(73, 101, 241);">Add Task</button> <button class="sc-fjdhpX bkXWNp" style="margin-right: 5px;">Download</button> <button class="sc-fjdhpX gKYhyw" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"> </div> </div>
```

There are multiple buttons with the same class and type value. However, I need to click only 'Expand All' button using CSS selector I got the error message no element found.

Comment: Where is a button whose class name = `Expand All`? or what is it a id of control?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is incomplete, So I am assuming here that the last button which has color: rgb(255, 255, 255); is the button you want to click.
So you can use this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var el = $('button[style^="color"]');
    if (el.length) {
        $(el).click(function() {
            alert("in place of this alert use your code");
        });
    }
});
```

or you can complete the code, or you can ask me if anything else is needed.